# CodeIgniter throws "Message: Call to a member function initialize() on null"

Tags: php, codeigniter

**welcome.php file**

```
  function formData(){
        if (empty($this->input->post('checkprocess'))) {
                        $email_config = Array(
                            'mailtype' => 'html',
                            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
                        );

                        $admin_email ='rockpokhrel@gmail.com';
                        $name = $this->input->post('full_name');
                        $email = $this->input->post('email');
                        $message = "Dear Admin, <br/>" .
                        "Contact Information of Users:" .'<br/>'.
                        "<b>Name</b> :- " . $this->input->post('full_name') .'<br/>'.
                        "<b>Email:-</b> " . $this->input->post('email') .'<br/>'.
                        "<b>Contact Number:-</b> " . $this->input->post('mob_num') .'<br/>'.'<br/>'.
                        "<b>Address:-</b> " . $this->input->post('address') .'<br/>'.'<br/>'.
                        "<b>Message:-</b> " . $this->input->post('message');
                        $this->load->library('email', $email_config);
                        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                        $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));
                        $this->email->to($admin_email);
                        $this->email->subject("Public Contact/Feedback");
                        $this->email->message($message);

                        if ($this->email->send()) {
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=REFRESH CONTENT=0;url='".base_url()."'>";exit();

                        $this->db->insert('tbl_contactusform',$email_config);
                                    redirect(base_url());
                            }
    }
}
```

**library/email.php file**

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.example.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '**********@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '************',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8'
);
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$htmlContent = '<h1>Sending email via SMTP server</h1>';
$htmlContent .= '<p>This email has sent via SMTP server from CodeIgniter application.</p>';

$this->email->to('**********@gmail.com');
$this->email->from('**********@gmail.com','MyWebsite');
$this->email->subject('How to send email via SMTP server in CodeIgniter');
$this->email->message($htmlContent);


$this->email->send();
```

I want to add email feature in website but I get this stack trace:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$email
>
> Filename: MX/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 304
>
> Backtrace:
>
> error and
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function initialize() on null
>
> Filename: E:\xampp\htdocs\website\application\libraries\email.php
>
> Line Number: 17

I am a beginner in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use email class you have to load the library by using

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

or

In `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('email');
```

Comment: i tried this way , in my welcome.php  ,                                              
  function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Mhome');
        $this->load->library('email');
    }

Comment: Just saw why did you add `library/email.php file`. You can add those configs in config.php and call them in code

Comment: not wrong. can do. But I prefer to do it in config.php. easy and secure

Comment: first remove those and add it in your controller and check

Comment: i add those code in controller , now i get these error   "This site can’t be reached
The webpage at http://localhost/website/welcome/formData might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED"

Comment: oh !!  thank you . it's work on local server but it's fine in remote server :)